# Function field for projective variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, elliptic-curves

Let $V$ be a projective variety over a field $k$. For any affine patch we can define the function field of $V$ to be $K(V)=K(V\cap\mathbb{A}^n)$, and these are all canonically isomorphic.

In Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", the author states that we may also view $K(V)$ as the field of rational functions $F(X)=f(x)/g(x)$ such that 1)$f$ and $g$ are homogeneous and of the same degree; 2) $g\not\in I(V)$; and 3) two functions $f_1/g_1$ and $f_2/g_2$ are identified is $f_1g_2-f_2g_1\in I(V)$.

My question is: why does the first definition of $K(V)$ imply that the $f$ and $g$ in the first condition of the second definition above are of the same degree?

Comment: If he says $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous then it's because he works in homogeneous coordinates. E.g. if $V$ is the projective line you could consider its function field to be $k(t)$ or you could consider it to be $k \left( \frac{X}{Y} \right)$ in homogeneous coordinates.